# select previous row based on group in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have this data.

```
 create table #temp_student_ticket
(
     student_ticket_id  int identity(1,1) primary key, 
    student_id int ,
   ticket_amount numeric(9,2)
)


insert into #temp_student_ticket
( 
    student_id,
    ticket_amount 
 )
values
(
   1,30.00
 ),(2,180.00),(1,75.00),(2,66.00)


select * from #temp_student_ticket
```

I need to select the previous row for the same student. Output should look like below.

```
 student_id     student_ticket_id     amount      prev_student_ticket_id        prev_amount
 1                1                20.00            NULL                          NULL
 1                3                75.00            1                             20.00 
 1                5                30.00            3                             75.00
 2                2                180.00           NULL                          NULL
 2                4                66.00            2                            180.00
```

What is the most optimized way to select this format on 50 million rows of table in MYSQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tst1.student_id, tst1.student_ticket_id, tst1.ticket_amount, 
       tst2.student_ticket_id prev_student_ticket_id, tst2.ticket_amount previous_amount
  FROM temp_student_ticket tst1 
  LEFT JOIN temp_student_ticket tst2
    ON (tst1.student_id = tst2.student_id
        AND tst1.student_ticket_id > tst2.student_ticket_id
        AND tst2.student_ticket_id = (SELECT MAX(tst3.student_ticket_id) 
                                        FROM temp_student_ticket tst3 
                                       WHERE tst3.student_id = tst1.student_id 
                                         AND tst3.student_ticket_id < tst1.student_ticket_id));
```